# Tomcat 8 non SSL to send requests to SSL web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl, tomcat8

I have a Java web application running on Tomcat 8.
this web server is being used by a group of users.
once the user does an action in the UI, the server side of the web application sends a REST request to a web service on a different server which has SSL\TLS configured on it.
To make it work i've used keytool to import the certificate into the keystore with this command

```
keytool -noprompt -importkeystore -srckeystore D:\temp\server.localdomain.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS -destkeypass keypwd -deststorepass storepwd
```

When running the 1st web server from my environment using a local jetty with this configuration

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security\keystore" -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security\keystore"
```

Everything works.

When running the 1st web server from production using Tomcat 8, the tomcat starts without error message but the 1st web server isn't reachable.

Note
I'm using a self signed certificate

Why does it work on my env with Jetty but not with Tomcat?

Comment: How do you actually perform the REST request?

Comment: using WebTarget and building it using invocationBuilder, but im sure that its not realted to it. the webserver isnt reachable at all when running on Tomcat with the new SSL configuration, the UI cant be loaded and once going to jetty everything ok

Comment: What actual errors are you getting from Tomcat?  Are you using the javax.net.debug property with Tomcat as well?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in any log file, my web application isnt loaded.
yes, i'm using the same javax.net.debug and other parameters in tomcat that work in jetty